# Atmel AVR ADMUX Register Not Taking Assigned Value

Tags: c, avr, cpu-registers, atmel, adc

I have the following enums and structs:

```
typedef enum reference{
    AREF = 0, //External on AREF pin
    AVCC = true << REFS0, //Analogue supply voltage
    I11 = true << REFS1, //Internal 1.1V reference
    I256 = true << REFS1 | true <<REFS0 //Internal 2.56 reference
} Reference;

typedef enum channel{
    ADC0 = 0,
    ADC1 = true << MUX0,
    ADC2 = true << MUX1,
    ADC3 = true << MUX0 | true << MUX1,
    ADC4 = true << MUX2,
    ADC5 = true << MUX2 | true << MUX0,
    ADC6 = true << MUX2 | true << MUX1,
    ADC7 = true << MUX2 | true << MUX1 | true << MUX0
    //If higher channels are needed continue using MUXn for n = 0-> 4 in a binary count.
} Channel;

typedef enum leftadjust{
    LADisabled = 0,
    LAEnabled = true << ADLAR
} LeftAdjust;

//Enums for ADCSRA
typedef enum adcenable{
    ADCDisabled = 0,
    ADCEnabled = true << ADEN
} ADCEnable;

typedef enum adcautotriggerenable{
    AutoTriggerDisabled = 0,
    AutoTriggerEnabled = true << ADATE
} ADCAutoTriggerEnable;

typedef enum adcinterruptenable{
    ADCIntteruptDisabled = 0,
    ADCInterruptEnabled = true << ADIE,
} ADCInterruptEnable;

typedef enum adcclockdivider{
    CDHalf = 0,
    CDQuarter = true << ADPS1,
    CDEighth = true << ADPS1 | true << ADPS0,
    CDSixteenth = true << ADPS2,
    CDThirtySecond = true << ADPS2 | true << ADPS0,
    CDSixtyFourth = true << ADPS2 | true << ADPS1,
    CDOneTwoEighth = true << ADPS2 | true << ADPS1| true << ADPS0
} ADCClockDivider;

///structs
typedef struct ADCSettings{
    Reference ref;
    LeftAdjust leftAdjust;
    Channel channel;
    ADCAutoTriggerEnable autoTrigger;
    ADCInterruptEnable interruptEnable;
    ADCClockDivider clockDivider;
    } ADCSettings;
```

This constructor function:

```
ADCSettings* NewADCSettings()
{
    return (ADCSettings*)malloc(sizeof(ADCSettings));
}
```

and then this function to set up my ADC:

```
void InitialiseADC(ADCSettings* settings)
{
    /*
        13CCs for a conversion. 50ns/cc therefore 0 clock division conversion time is 13 * 50ns =650ns.
        for 50us; 50us/950ns = 77.
        We have 16,32,64 and 128, 64 gives a time of 61us which is in range.
    */
    ADMUX = (settings->ref | settings ->leftAdjust | settings->channel);
    //ADMUX = true << REFS0 | true << MUX1 | true << MUX0; //REFSn sets voltage ref source, MUXn sets channel

    DIDR0 = true << ADC3D; //DIDR is digital input disable (makes a pin analogue)
    ADCSRA = true << ADEN | settings ->autoTrigger | settings ->interruptEnable | settings ->leftAdjust | settings->clockDivider;
    //ADCSRA = true << ADEN | true << ADPS2 | true << ADPS1; //ADPS1 & ADPS2 gives 64 scale

}
```

As you can see, I'm in the middle of refactoring this to try and make it a nice library function rather than just setting it up the way I need it this once. The commented out lines worked just fine.

When I run this, I believe `ADMUX` should be assigned `67` but it instead takes the value of `64` which, if I'm not mistaken is just the `REFS0` getting set and neither `MUX0` nor `MUX1`.

The register is 8-bits so it should be able to hold a value up to 255.

Here's my `main.c` for completeness:

```
#include "misc/utilities.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "USART/USART.h"
#include "ADC/ADC.h"

int main()
{
    ADCSettings* settings = NewADCSettings();
    settings->autoTrigger = false;
    settings->channel=ADC3;
    settings->clockDivider=CDSixtyFourth;
    settings->interruptEnable=false;
    settings->leftAdjust=false;
    settings->ref=AVCC;
    InitialiseADC(settings);
    while (true) 
    {
        int adcReading = GetADCConversion();
        Tx_Line(IntToString(adcReading));
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

The USART lib and Utilities lib have been used before so I'm pretty sure they're okay.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `REFS0` (and other constants you use as shift amounts)?  Also I really don't like the shifting of `bool` constants. Use `1U` instead.

Comment: REFS0 is defined in `avr/io.h` with: `#define REFS0 6`

Comment: Do you really have `malloc` properly implemented on your system? you never check it's return value. Are you sure it is working?

Comment: `malloc` is in `stdlib.h` which is imported in `ADC.c` which contains the ADC funcs

Comment: How about getting rid of it? Allocate `settings` statically. I don't see any good reason to do otherwise anyway.

Comment: `true` might happen to be 1, but that is not a reason to use it instead of `1`.

Comment: @stark Well, it is guaranteed to be `1`. but still not a good reason.

Comment: okay so replacing the struct with a bunch of params makes no difference, I'm still getting the same errors. Is there maybe something wrong with the way I'm doing my enums?

Comment: What errors? You have not mentioned any errors. Do you mean the same behavior of reading unexpected value from the register?

Comment: Does the integer promotion rule apply to defining an `enum` value, such as `ADC3 = true << MUX0 | true << MUX1`? It's not really an intialisation.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good question... I would get rid of this `enum` and replace it with `#define`s anyway. Code should not rely on numerical value of `enum`.

Comment: by errors I meant it's getting 64 and not 67

Comment: @EugeneSh. really? How come?

Comment: Have you replaced the `true` with `1U` yet? Debugging is an adventure.

Comment: Yes, @WeatherVane '1U' doesn't make any difference. Just grabbing some food then I'll try `#define`ing all my enums

Comment: @Persistence `enum` is good for having names for stuff which don't care how they are numbered. Such as state of state machines, days of the week, and return status of functions. The things that you will always assign and compare to the same type.

Comment: do not use dynamic allocation on tiny uCs like this.

Comment: So I've replaced all my enums with `#define`s and it's still assigning 64 to the ADMUX

Comment: can you *hardcode* the value of 67, and then read it back? BTW, how do you actually check it's value?

Comment: If you hardcode in 67 it still shows as 64. I'm checking by reading it from the watch window

Comment: I forgot to run my `InitialiseUSART()` function... The registers seem to sort themselves out after a few more lines of code have been run

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there wasn't a problem with my ADC setup at all.

The issues with the registers seemed to just be a delay in the simulator updating the value in the watch window.

The reason I wasn't getting values through was because I forgot to run my `InitialiseUART()` command from the library.

Moral of the story, ensure you initialise all of your peripherals.

---

Other advice from comments:

1. Don't use dynamic memory assignment on small uCs.
2. Don't rely on the numerical values of enums, use `#define`